# How can you add additional (static) input arguments to a referenced function in mapslices?

Tags: julia

Assuming I have a function defined in this way:

```
function InCylinder(cpt1, cpt2, radius, pt)
    # return if pt is inside cylinder defined by cpt1,cpt2,radius
end
```

I would like to apply this function to all points in a matrix like this:

```
testM = rand(3,100)
```

I found that I could technically use a function called `mapslices` to pass my points from the matrix to the function. That should look something like this:

```
mapslices(InCylinder,testM,1)
```

As you can imagine, this doesn't work, since `InCylinder` requires many more (static) input values. I would like to avoid copying these into the matrix, given that `cpt1`, `cpt2` and `radius` do not change for all `pt` in `testM`.

**How could I pass `cpt1`, `cpt2` and `radius` into `InCylinder` without too much redundancy?**

*PS: I know iterating over the matrix is an option, but that is not answering my question.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an anonymous function:

```
mapslices(x -> InCylinder(cpt1, cpt2, radius, x), testM, 1)
```

Comment: Any idea if this is the most efficient way? I read anonymous functions are fairly slow - should I try to just pass the whole matrix instead of single points into that function?

Comment: I don't think you should notice a big performance hit, but benchmarks are the only way you can really know. Also, something to look forward to, on Julia 0.5 anonymous functions no longer have a performance pentaly.